# Python pygame exe build with cx_freeze TCL_LIBRARY error

Tags: python, build, pygame, command-prompt, cx-freeze

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HosXxXE24hA) to make a snakegame in pygame. Here is my setup.py code:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("snake.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Snake",
    options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"], "include_files":["apple.png","Aenemy.png","bomb.png","cherry.png","enemy.png","fire.png","iceimg.png","snakebod(2).png","snakebod.png","Explosion.wav","Explosion2.wav","jump.wav","Pickup_Coin.wav","Powerup.wav","openingsong.mp3","highscores.txt",]}},

    description = "Snake Game made in python with pygame.",
    executables = executables
    )
```

When I try to build that in the command prompt I get this error

> C:\Users\Accounts\Documents\snake>C:/Python35/python setup.py build running build running build_exe File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 597, in load_tkinter tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
>
> File "C:\Python35\lib\os.py", line 681, in getitem raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'

and it doesn't build. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: always add full error message.

Comment: `tcl` (and `tk`) is library used by `tkinter`

Comment: List all your imports please that will really help.

Comment: imports in the game are pygame, time, and random. In the setup its just cx_Freeze.

Comment: @furus,  - stack overflow won't let me post the whole error but here's the end of the command prompt text:
C:\Users\Accounts\Documents\snake>C:/Python35/python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe

  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py", line 597, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "C:\Python35\lib\os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'

C:\Users\Accounts\Documents\snake>

Answer (score 9):

I was getting a similar error and solved it successfully this morning!
Add following lines to your setup.py code

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\tcl\\tk8.6"
```

you may need to replace C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6 and C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tk8.6 with the exact path of tcl8.6 and tk8.6 on your system respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows operating system:

Add 2 environment variable named TCL_Library and TK_Library in your machines user and system variable

[TK_Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKMSv.jpg)

[TCL_Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Lx3.jpg)

[Env variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVhNS.jpg)