# I cant convert Python to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I created a python script and wanted to give it to my friends. So I go to youtube and follow [this](https://youtu.be/EY6ZCPxqEtM?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdLkP8MrOXLe_rKuf6r80KO) video, (after trying many others). I run it and get a TLC Library error. No problem, I went and found an answer to solve this right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939356/python-pygame-exe-build-with-cx-freeze-tcl-library-error) on stack over flow. I input that piece of code, (changing Python35 to 36 and making sure my TLC is in the same place it says). I run it but get a different error, in my cmd prompt it says

```
File "C:\Users\Brain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 750, in __init__
    parts = version.split(".")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' "
```

I just want to make my game an send to friends.
Please help. I'm using Python 3.6.3 and am just so frustrated. I've tried to do this for over a day now. (Also I made my game from [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlEgNdBJEO-lqvqL5nNNZC6KoRdSrhQwK) playlist, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with it.)

Comment: Take a look at pyinstaller, I think py2exe only supports Python 2.6 and Python 2.7

Comment: @clfaster He is using `cx_freeze` that supports Python 2.7 or higher (Including Python 3) but I would also advise to look at [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: i tried pyinstaller, but i had trouble with that also. If you could link an up to date tutorial that would be great.

Comment: Here is the latest manual: -->https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of the exception? What you've shown is just the last part, and the error may have occurred earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a version in your metadata. Newer versions of cx_Freeze check for this instead of simply failing with a strange error when the version is not specified.